# Django raster, not add raster to BD Postgis

Tags: postgis, raster, geodjango, django, django-raster

I am new in this world, and I am trying to make Django Raster work, I have already followed all the instructions of:
https://django-raster.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html
But at the moment of creating the raster with the administrator, (I attached a .tiff image) I receive the following error::

> The process does not have access to the file because it is being used
>   by another process.

Also when attaching a tiff file a new tiff file with the same name is generated plus a randomized code example: test.tiff generates a test_1dcv.tiff

I am currently working with GeoDjango + Postgis in Window and Celery is False in settings.

[image: The process does not have access to the file because it is being used by another process]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures, and please provide any additional information as an [edit] to your question  (there is a button beneath it) rather than as a comment.

Comment: I edited the publication and read the article thank you very much